# Flutter : How to set the hours, minutes and seconds to 0 from today's date irrespective of the time?

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to implement something which requires the date to be set at 00:00:00 for the next day.
For example :

`DateTime? created_at = DateTime.now(); //lets say Jul 25 10:35:90`

Now I want a variable `start_date` whose value should be `Jul 26 00:00:00`

How can I achieve this ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like below

```
DateTime? now = DateTime.now(); //lets say Jul 25 10:35:90
var lastMidnight = DateTime(now.year, now.month,  now.day + 1);
```

It return `2022-07-26 00:00:00.000`

Comment: This will give inconsistent value . If the day is 31. Then you add a 1 to it. You will try to create a date time with day value 32

Comment: No. dart automatically handles that and returns the first day of the next month. Please check in dartpad.

Comment: @Arijeet : Yes correct, You are right...